# Android reverse gecode

Tags: android, permissions

```
public Location getLocation(String provider) {
    if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(provider)) {

                  locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider,
                MIN_TIME_FOR_UPDATE, MIN_DISTANCE_FOR_UPDATE, this);
        if (locationManager != null) {
            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            return location;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I am getting an error call requires permission which may be rejected by user.how it can be solved?

In manifest i have provided these set of permission

Comment: Can you please post the stacktrace when the error occurs? Thank you.

Comment: @Rajesh v whats your targetSdk?

Comment: Add access_fine_location and Access_coarse_location permission in manifest file.If you are using marshmallow(or >SDK 21) for testing then you have to add permission dynamically at runtime https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html